# Issue with gl_LightSource attenuation factors in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, phong

I'm attempting to use the Phong/Blinn shading model, and I've been having troubles getting the attenuation to work correctly.  For some reason the geometry facing the point light turn completely white.  I'm particularly stuck because (1) The code works perfectly fine in fixed functionality (i.e. all my attenuation/position factors are set just fine), and (2) it works fine if I replace:

```
att = 1.0 / (gl_LightSource[i].constantAttenuation + gl_LightSource[i].linearAttenuation * dist + gl_LightSource[i].quadraticAttenuation * dist * dist);
```

with

```
att = 1.0 / (1 + 0.1*dist);
```

That is, all my other calculations (distance, direction, normalization) seem to be working fine, but there's an issue (somehow) with this line of code.  I'll be happy to post more if need be, but this seems to be where the issue is.

P.S. Running Windows 7, and my OpenGL version is printed as 4.3.

Update:

Here's a printscreen of the issue.

[error image http://snag.gy/EWpOl.jpg](http://snag.gy/EWpOl.jpg)

and what it looks like with `att = 1.0 / (1 + 0.1*dist);`

[correct image http://snag.gy/NiYvA.jpg](http://snag.gy/NiYvA.jpg)

Comment: What am I doing wrong?  As I said, any geometry facing the point light get rendered completely white (as they obviously should not be) with the first attenuation term.  See update for picture.

Comment: How are you calculating `dist`?

Comment: `lightDir = vec3(gl_LightSource[i].position - ecPos);  dist = length(lightDir);` (ecPos is set to gl_Position in the vertex shader.)

Comment: Have you tried using just the one light and hard-coding the index 0 instead of using `i`?

Comment: Yes, I have.  I did some further testing, and for some reason `gl_LightSource[0].constantAttenuation, gl_LightSource[0].linearAttenuation, gl_LightSource[0].quadraticAttenuation` are all getting set to 0 regardless of calling `glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 1.0); glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.1);`